# What is the use of Task with async?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, webapi

What if I don't use Task in the async method? I have searched a lot but able to understand why we use `Task` with `async`. Please suggest some point, as both are asynchronously Thanks in advance.

Example of `async` `Task` signature:

```
//Controller with async and task 
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateNewBug([FromBody] BugTrackerRequest bugTrackerRequest)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
        var Request = await _projectDetails.CreateNewBug(bugTrackerRequest);
        if (Request > 0)
        {
           return Ok("Success");
        }
    }

   return StatusCode(500, new { Message = "Something went wrong" });
}
```

Comment: Please put enough effort so that the code can be read. Also, you put `enter code here` and `**strong text**` in random places, please get rid of those too. And overall, it's not at all clear what you're asking

Comment: @Camilo sorry for the inconvenience there is some typing issue happen next time will make sure the same.

Comment: That's ok, you can always [edit] your question to improve it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What if i don't use Task in the async method?

Well, it is by design.

If you want to use `async` you have a limit set of valid return types<sup>*</sup>:

- `void`
- `Task`
- `Task<T>`
- `task-like type`
- `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`
- `IAsyncEnumerator<T>`

<sub>* leaving out lambda's and anonomyous methods here.</sub>

Anything else is invalid. And `void` is considered to be bad practice.

E.g.:

```
public async int DoIt()
```

will cause this error:

> Error CS1983  The return type of an async method must be void, Task, Task, a task-like type, IAsyncEnumerable, or IAsyncEnumerator

Also, the `async` modifier by itself does not do a lot. I believe this is a general misconception.

It does not make your code "asynchronous" It is the combination of tasks, together with the `await` keyword which allows you to execute a task asyncronously but yet continue afterward in an subsequent manner - and that is what the `async/await` construct is for.

I highly recommend you read mr. Cleary's blog about the subject:

https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html

As he state it:

> The “async” keyword enables the “await” keyword in that method and changes how method results are handled. That’s all the async keyword does! It does not run this method on a thread pool thread, or do any other kind of magic. The async keyword only enables the await keyword (and manages the method results).

---

As by comment: you only need async if you want to use await. You only use await if you need something to be done after the asynchronous method.

Also: a task might be asynchrounous, but does not have to be. For the sake of simplicity lets assume in the following examples they are:

Some examples:

```
// no async, yet possibly asynchronous.
// Task can be returned directly, it's still asynchronous.
public Task<int> ProcessData()
{
   return _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

```
// no async, yet possibly asynchronous.
// returning the task directly
public async Task<int> ProcessData()
{
   var result = await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
   //await needed if you want to continue here after the task is completed.
   if (result < 1)
       throw new ValidationException("should be higher then 1");

   return result;   
}
```

The following 2 examples does not add anything and/or are invalid:

```
// returning the task directly
public Task<int> ProcessData()
{
   //ERROR: missing async keyword
   var result = await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(); 
   return result;   
}
```

```
// returning the task directly
public async Task<int> ProcessData() //WARNING: missing await keyword
{
   //WARNING: missing await keyword
   return _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(); 
}
```

Comment: So you mean to say if am using async  then have to use task to get the output also it's a good practice right?  .....thanks!!

Comment: Basically: you only need `async` if you want to use `await`. You only use `await` if you need something to be done *after* the asynchronous method.